# matplotlib subplots empty when attempting to change font size of axes ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had a script for plotting a single plot and adapted it for 2 subplots. When attempting to change the font size of the axes ticks via `tick_params`, all I get is a single empty plot. I've isolated this issue to the calling of this function. The following MWE runs fine with the `tick_params` calls commented out, but produces an incorrect figure if they're used. How can I modify this code to work with the subplots?

```
x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
y = x

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
mystr = 'Some plot 1'
plt.title(mystr, fontsize=16)
# plt.axes().tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)
# plt.axes().tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=16)
plt.grid()


plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
mystr = 'Some plot 2'
plt.title(mystr, fontsize=16)
# plt.axes().tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)
# plt.axes().tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=16)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.gca().tick_params()` would work here.  Better is to use `ax = plt.subplot(...)` and then `ax.plot(...)`, `ax.set_xlabel(...)`, `ax.tick_params(...)`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the subplot by `plt.subplot()`, access the `axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` individually.

I would try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
y = x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[0].set_title('Some plot 1', fontsize=16)
ax[0].set_xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
ax[0].set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
ax[0].tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=16)
ax[0].tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=16)
ax[0].grid()

ax[1].plot(x, y)
ax[1].set_title('Some plot 2', fontsize=16)
ax[1].set_xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
ax[1].set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
ax[1].tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=16)
ax[1].tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=16)
ax[1].grid()
```

A very similar question was actually asked on the official `matplotlib` GitHub repository. So if you like to have a more detailed look on why `subplots` work this way, you might want to read this [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12318).

---

Also, I would like to add: in your example, the figures slightly overlap. This could be solved by calling `fig.tight_layout()` after you defined your subplots.